# label Printer GODEX does not pint EZPL

Tags: printing, label, zpl

I use vb6.
I am trying to print in a printer GODEX 500 in EZPL (which is supposed to be the default language of the printer).

I can print with ZPL but not with EZPL
This code works (ZPL)

```
printer.print "^XA    
printer.print "^LH0,0    
printer.print "^CF0,50,50    
printer.print "^FO16,16    
printer.print "^FD1^FS    
printer.print "^CF0,30,25    
printer.print "^FO340,16    
printer.print "^FD2022^FS     
printer.print "^PQ1,0,1,Y    
printer.print "^CF0,35,35    
printer.print "^FO130,66    
printer.print "^FDFQ^FS    
printer.print "^CF0,30,25    
printer.print "^FO310,66    
printer.print "^FDAGP^FS       
printer.print "^CF0,35,35    
printer.print "^FO130,110    
printer.print "^FDPET^FS        
printer.print "^CF0,30,30    
printer.print "^FO130,155    
printer.print "^FD100ml^FS               
printer.print "^CF0,30,25    
printer.print "^FO260,155    
printer.print "^FD^FS    
printer.print "^FT20,158^BQA,2,4    
printer.print "^FDLA,MyCode R 1 1^FS            
printer.print "^PQ1,0,1,Y    
printer.print "^XZ"
```

But this code does not work (in EZPL):

```
printer.print "^Q25,4"    
printer.print "^W50"     
printer.print "^H10"     
printer.print "^P1"     
printer.print "^S2"    
printer.print "^AD"        
printer.print "^C1"     
printer.print "^R0"     
printer.print "~Q+0"     
printer.print "^O0"     
printer.print "^D0"     
printer.print "^E35"     
printer.print "~R200"     
printer.print "^L"     
printer.print "W30 , 34, 5, 2, m, 8, 5, 7, 0"     
printer.print "MyCode"      
printer.print "E"
```

Does anyone know how I can send EZPL commands to the printer?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check if the printer supports EPL (most likely yes), then you should configure the printer to work with the EPL language.
You can do so by getting the [allcv report from the printer](http://www.thezcorner.com/doku.php?id=language:sgd) then you have to look at the "device.languages" property to see what's the language currently set and what are the languages supported.
If you need to convert the printer to EPL, have a look [here](http://www.thezcorner.com/doku.php?id=language:epl)
If none of these works, I would doublecheck the code to be sure it is correct and once the EPL printer is visible in the printer list, you can create an example label using zebradesigner and selecting the EPL printer and using the [print to file option](http://www.thezcorner.com/doku.php?id=software:zd3:print_to_file) to get a correct code to test

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. All this is new to me. My printer is GODEX brand, not ZEBRA. Do I have to install the Zebra drivers to do what you have written?
I can send EZPL code from GoLabel or QLabel sw, and it prints the labels fine, but not from vb6, where it only prints ZPL labels, not EZPL